# Not Allowing change the hashmap value after adding in arraylist

Tags: java, php, android, arraylist, hashmap

I have this arraylist and another for hashmap

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> agentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 HashMap<String, String> agentproperty = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

I have received jArray from php file. and trying to put it in the array using hashmap.

```
 JSONArray jArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_AGENT);
      String id = null;
      String name = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject a = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            id = a.getString(TAG_AGENTID);
            name = a.getString(TAG_NAME);

            agentproperty.put("AGENTID", id);
            agentproperty.put("NAME", name);

            Log.d("id",id);
            Log.d("name",name);
            agentList.add(agentproperty);


    }
                Log.d("firstperson",String.valueOf(agentList.get(0)));
                Log.d("secondperson",String.valueOf(agentList.get(1)));
```

I can get

```
id 1, hame cathy; id 2, name john
```

for the log inside loop. But from the last log, I am getting

id 2, name john; id 2, name john
It seems the value of agentproperty is changed even after adding in arraylist. 
I tried taking the agentList.add(agentproperty); outside of loop. Didnt work. Only inserts the last value (id 2, name john). Any idea how can i populate this array with all the values I get from loop. I will need to use agentList in listview.

Comment: make sure you have unique id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move

```
HashMap<String, String> agentproperty = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

inside the `for` loop

Comment: Thanks. It worked. It was minor issue. But mindblowing.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is. You have to create a new instance of the `HashMap` at every iteration, otherwise you will override the value for a given key, if an entry already exists

Comment: at every iteration you are overriding the values for "AGENTID" and "NAME" because it is the way HashMap works. If it does check if it has an entry for the key. If it has it just replace the value with last you provided, otherwise it will create a new entry.

Comment: Excellent.Instantiation inside loop, that was what required.thanks